# Automatically killed Mysql database restoration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, azure

I have 9 databases in AWS RDS aurora mysql. it's size around 500GB so I want to migrate all databases to azure MYSQL. The database aren't in use so no need to live replication or anything. I just dump all databases and restore that on azure mysql. I have one linux os with 500GB storage and it's running on EC2 instance. I dumped all databases and restored on azure mysql except one database. that database size is 18GB. when I try to restore that it's automatically killed and additional information my linux instance. storage size is 500GB and only around 250 filled so here there is no system storage insufficient or anything.

except this 18Gb database all other databases are restored even one database size is 250GB. I don't know why it's killed and it's not running so long time then shows killed. when i start the restoration it's quickly shows killed. how to resolve this issue?

[image]

I've taken again dumped the same database and tried to restore but I facing same issue.

Comment: Try to add `-v` as parameter. This will add the statement that is currently run to the output. (see: `mysql --help`, and  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_verbose )  The final statement before `Killed` should be the on that is causing this problem.

Comment: @Luuk I added -v but I didn't get info about the killed

Comment: Then more info is needed. Like any errors in the log files of MySQL.  (see: [How to see log files in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql))

Comment: @Luuk I will check the log file before that I clarify one thing, it's not running sometimes, and restored half data and threw killed. when I start the restoration suddenly throw killed.

Comment: @Luuk I checked the system logs I find something like out of memory and I attached the error log below please find that and tell me one thing if I increase the RAM size will this issue be solved or not?  Error:  oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=user.slice,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-554.scope,task=mysql,pid=73332,uid=0
[1021548.103941] Out of memory: Killed process 73332 (mysql) total-vm:445612kB, anon-rss:377308kB, file-rss:2640kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:844kB oom_score_adj:0

Comment: You should not leave that kind of stuff in a comment, but you should use [edit] to expand the question with this extra info.  Unfortunately the info is not enough to say anything because 1) I do not know the contents of this backup file 2) I do not know anything about the server.   Because of these two reasons I cannot say that your problem will be solved. (But I also cannot say that it will not be solved.... )